# Transforme a column into a list inside a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as

df

```
COL1 COL2 
A    "[Lasius_niger]" 
B    "[Canis_lupus,Feis_cattus]"
C    "[Cattus_stigmatizans,Cattus_cattus"]
D    "[Apis_mellifera]"
```

and in my code I iterate each row of `df$COL2` into a commande where I need that the cotent is a list.
So I need to transforme the `df$COL2` into a list inside the dataframe

So I should get something like that I guess:

```
COL1 COL2 
A    "Lasius_niger" 
B    "Canis_lupus","Feis_cattus"
C    "Cattus_stigmatizans","Cattus_cattus"
D    "Apis_mellifera"
```

does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove opening and closing square brackets using `gsub` and split string on comma.

```
df$COL2 <- strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', df$COL2), ',')
str(df)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ COL1: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
# $ COL2:List of 4
#  ..$ : chr "Lasius_niger"
#  ..$ : chr  "Canis_lupus" "Feis_cattus"
#  ..$ : chr  "Cattus_stigmatizans" "Cattus_cattus"
#  ..$ : chr "Apis_mellifera"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(COL1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), COL2 = c("[Lasius_niger]", 
"[Canis_lupus,Feis_cattus]", "[Cattus_stigmatizans,Cattus_cattus]", 
"[Apis_mellifera]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks and how do i use each row as a list content ? for instance for the row3 get something similar to ```c("Cattus_stigmatizans","Cattus_cattus")``` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `stri_extract_all_words` in the `stringi` package as follows

```
df$COL2 <- stringi::stri_extract_all_words(df$COL2)

str(df)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ COL1: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
# $ COL2:List of 4
#  ..$ : chr "Lasius_niger"
#  ..$ : chr  "Canis_lupus" "Feis_cattus"
#  ..$ : chr  "Cattus_stigmatizans" "Cattus_cattus"
#  ..$ : chr "Apis_mellifera"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
df$COL2 <- str_extract_all(df$COL2, "\\w+")
```

---

Or another option from `qdapRegex`

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_square(df$COL2, extract = TRUE)
```